# How do I test for button press on pause command in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script, in which a user reads a disclaimer, then they press any key to continue, or "E" to exit. It looks something like this:

```
@echo off
echo (some disclaimer text here)
echo.
echo once you fully understand this message, press any key to continue, or press "E" to exit.
::I know that pause doesn't take input, I'm just using it as a placeholder for something
pause>nul
cls
echo Welcome!
pause
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks!

To clarify, I want to exit the *second* they press the E key. I have seen it done before, but I forgot where it saw it.

Comment: [`Choice.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) and [`set /p`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) are the two common methods of prompting the user for input, but I don't think either will trap *any* key.  I don't think either will do much of anything with space, for example.

Comment: `pause` only pauses. `set /p` waits for input. For example, with: `set /p id="Enter input: "`  You enter "e" and press enter, and you can set a label to go to if id is set to e.

Comment: @bryc What I mean is, I want to exit the second they press the E key. I have seen it done before, but I forgot where it saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Choice.exe` does what you describe, though it doesn't have an option for "any key".  You can specify a specific key such as "Y" below.

```
echo once you fully understand this message, press "Y" to continue, or press "E" to exit.
choice /c ey
if errorlevel 2 goto :welcome
if errorlevel 1 goto :canceled

rem User pressed Ctrl+C

:canceled
rem User pressed E.  Do cancel stuff.
goto :eof

:welcome
rem User pressed Y.  Do welcome stuff
echo Welcome!
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great!...Except for not being able to press any key, but I added more options, like "S" to go to the settings, so this solution is superior.